# Taking woman and biological child out of China

Tags: china, children

Suppose am from abroad and I have a child with a Chinese woman in China, and we are not married. How can I take my Chinese wife and child with me out of China? Is this possible or even likely to happen without a marriage?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you listed on the child's birth certificate?

Comment: Adults do not get "taken out of" countries, they leave countries, and one of the big things they need is a country to go that will take them in. If you don't intend for her to return to China, this belongs in Expatriates. If you just want them to visit you "abroad" wherever that is, please say so.

Comment: What is the citizenship of the child? In many countries, if you are the biological father you can become the legal father and as the legal father your citizenship passes to the child. That requires some paperwork. however.

Comment: You say you are not married, but you refer to her as your Chinese wife. Slightly confusing matters. Is the woman just the mother of your child, or are you actually married, but the marriage is not official/notarized/recognized?